# Infinite Markov chain

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I have to work out this question to study for my exam and i have the memo, but I honestly have no idea what they are trying to do in the memo. Is there a better/more understandable way for me to do it? Or can someone please try to explain what they are doing in the memo?

The question is:

We have a infinite supply of electronic components. Let $Z_i$ denote the lifetime of the $i^{th}$ component (in days) i = 1,2,3.... also assume the lifetimes are i.i.d . Also let P($Z_i$ =k) = $a_k$

Then $X_n$ be the age of the component which is on at time n and set $X_n$=0 if a failure occurs at time n. Argue that {$X_n$,n $\ge$ 0} is a markov chain and write down its matrix.

Now i understand that there are only two possible transitions: k to 0 if the part fails on day k+1 or k to k+1 if it continues to work, but now the memo loses me as it states:
$$
\begin{split}
p_{k,0} &= P(Z_1 = k + 1|Z_1 \ge k + 1)
         = \frac{a_{k+1}}{\sum_{i=k+1}^\infty a_i}\\
p_{k,k+1} &= P(Z_1  > k + 1|Z_1 \ge k + 1) = 1 - p_{k,0}
\end{split}
$$

The parts i don't understand is how they define $p_{k,0}$ and $p_{k,k+1}$

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What happens after a component fails? Do you turn on another one, and its age is measured starting from the time it was turned on? If so, $p_{k,0}$ is the probability that the component which currently has been running for $k$ days will fail on the next day. $p_{k,k+1}$ is the probability that the component which currently has been running for $k$ days will not fail on the next day, and thus will have been running for $k+1$ days on the next day. The rest of it is just figuring out what those probabilities are. If you don't understand what your notes did, just do it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lifetime of a component is literally the number of days until the component fails. So  $Z=k+1$ means the component failed exactly on day $k+1$. The event $\{Z\ge k+1\}$ is the event that the component is still functioning on day $k$; it may or may not have survived to day $k+1$.

In terms of the $X$'s: If today's value for $X$ is $k$, that means that today's component has been alive for $k$ days so far. Tomorrow there are two possibilities: (a) the component fails before end of day (meaning tomorrow's value for $X$ is reset to zero), or (b) the component is still alive (meaning tomorrow's value for $X$ is $k+1$). Thus the transition probabilities are calculated as
$$\begin{align}
p_{k,0}:&=P(\text{component failed on day $k+1$}\mid \text{component functioning on day $k$}) \\
&= P(Z=k+1\mid Z\ge k+1)
\end{align}
$$
and
$$\begin{align}
p_{k,k+1}&:=P(\text{component functioning on day $k+1$}\mid \text{component functioning on day $k$}) \\
&= P(Z\ge k+2\mid Z\ge k+1)\\
&=P(Z>k+1\mid Z\ge k+1)
\end{align}
$$